# how to translate more than one word discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Hello guys currently I'm using this command for my bot

```py
@client.command(name="translator", aliases=['ts','TS','Ts'])   
async def translator(ctx , message, frm=None,*, to=None):
  if to==None and frm==None:
    await ctx.send('Your words here')
   else: 
     google=translators.google(message, from_language=frm , to_language=to)
     await ctx.send(google)
```

but the problem is I cant translate more than one word. how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using `"Your words here"`?

Answer (score 0):

so I edited my code to this and it works.

```
    @client.command(name="translator", aliases=['ts','TS','Ts'])   
    async def translator(ctx , frm=None, to=None,*,message):
     if to==None and frm==None:
      await ctx.send('Your words here')
     else: 
      google=translators.google(message, from_language=frm , to_language=to)
      await ctx.send(google)
```

so now user have to choose input and output  first then they'll give the bot their sentence .